# Are multiple call signatures useful in a single object type?

Tags: typescript

It is possible to have more than one *call signature* in an *object type*:

```
interface MyInterface {
    (x:number, y:number) : number
    (s:string):void
}
```

The language does not prohibit this, but is this ever useful? Is it possible to construct an (not null) expression of that object type?

Comment: Why not? If you use this signature as a callback signature, it could be handy, you could at least make some kind of callback depending on certain conditions

Comment: @Icepickle: an example, maybe, please? Note, I'm specifically talking about call signatures, not method signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The language does not prohibit this, but is this ever useful

For modeling how *many* JavaScript libraries work. E.g. consider getter/setter definitions:

```
interface GetSet {
    (x:number) : void;
    ():number;
}

var getSet: GetSet; 

getSet(123); // set
var config = getSet(); // get
```

> Is it possible to construct an (not null) expression of that object type

Easily:

```
interface GetSet {
    (x:number) : void;
    ():number;
}

var getSet: GetSet; 

getSet(123); // set
var config = getSet(); // get

// SAMPLE
function sampleGetSet(x:number): void;
function sampleGetSet(): number;
function sampleGetSet(x?:number){
    if (x == void 0){
        return 123; // getter
    }
    else {
        var something = x; // setter
    }
}
// Allowed as it matches the signature
getSet = sampleGetSet;
```

Comment: Note, I'm specifically talking about call signatures, not method signatures. Your reply applies to method signatures. I understand that method signature overloads are useful exactly for that reason. But I cannot see how call signature overloads can be used

Comment: @zespri converted the *whole answer* to use call signatures. You can see them being used now

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing a specific case, it's a bit hard to show an example how you could use this, but you could have something like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
  (x: number, y: number): number
  (x: string): void
}

enum ActionType {
  T1, T2
}

class SomeClass {
  public handleSomething(action: ActionType, handler: MyInterface): boolean {
    var result: boolean = false;
    switch (action) {
      case ActionType.T1:
        result = handler(1, 2) > 5;
        break;
      case ActionType.T2:
        handler('test');
        result = true;
        break;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

In this case, your interface is just a callback signature, allowing you to call the `handler` with more than 1 method.

I am not sure however what you meant with: 'constructing an expression of that object type'

Comment: As far as your last sentence goes, this is exactly what is missing from your answer from my perspective. Your `handleSomething` method accepts a parameter of `MyInterface` type. How do you construct an expression of this type in order to pass it to this method? How is whatever you pass as `handler` initially created? I like the example, btw, thank you!